# Why are there hidden columns in linux txt files?

Tags: linux, file, multiple-columns, edit, hidden

i cannot explain why this happen when i was editing this fileA,

```
head fileA -n 3
10010    NC_000002.12    161136926       161236175oding
10012629NC_000005.10A2-1136080497       136080596cRNA
10012630NC_000023.1188  145994783q27.3  145994859

head fileA -n 3|cut -f 2
TANK
VTRNA2-1
MIR888
```

i have deleted and regenerate the file but this still happen
please help

Moreover,

```
more fileA|grep "TANK"
10010   NC_000002.12    161136926       161236175oding
```

Is it possible that some columns are hidden?

Comment: You shouldn't use `more` for this purpose, use `cat` instead or call `grep "TANK" fileA`.

Comment: @Klaus same result with `cat` and `grep "TANK" fileA`

Comment: yes it should be it just depends on what you like and sometimes you grep more things so you can use `grep "TANK" fileA | grep "..."`

Comment: Hey @once, if you found my answer satisfying , will you consider accepting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probable issue is that there are `backspace` characters in the text file.
Here is a demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    printf("foo\tTANK\t\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bspace\n");
}
```

Compile this into an executable called test:

```
$ ./test 
foo    space
$ ./test | cut -f1
foo
$ ./test | cut -f2
TANK
$ ./test | cut -f3
space
```

`\b` is a way to tell C to put in the backspace character. Inside your file, all the characters are kept, including the TANK characters. But when displaying in a terminal, the backspace characters take the caret back one character per backspace, and if other content is then printed, the already-printed characters will be overwritten.

If you need to see the content of a file containing stuff like backspace characters, try looking at the file using a hex editor. It will allow you to see all details.

Alternatively, using an editor like vi or gedit will usually also display these characters.

Comment: thank you! that's the answer, and apart from \b there are also \r
the file turn back to normal after
`more fileA |sed -e 's/[\b\r]//g'> newfileA`